# Finding the top log n elements of an unsorted list in linear time

Tags: time, queue, heap, priority-queue, selection-sort

I was given a question to find the top log(n) elements in an unsorted array. I know that I can do this in O(n) time with a selection algorithm to find the log(n)-th largest element and then find all elements larger than it. However, would it be possible to use a heap or other priority queue to do it in O(n) time as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the top k items from an unsorted list, you employ the the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm to partition the array such that the first k elements are at the beginning of the array.

Quickselect is, on average, O(n). However, in pathological cases it can take O(n^2) time.

Using a heap, selecting the top k elements from a list of n is O(n log k). If you're taking the first log(n) items, then `k = log(n)`, and your complexity is  O(n log(log(n)).

From a performance perspective, using a heap to select the top log(n) items from a list will almost certainly be faster than using Quickselect. The reason is that Quickselect, even though it's (on average) linear, it has a high constant. It takes almost the same time to select the top 10 items from a list of 1,000,000 as it does to select the top 100,000 items. But [my research](https://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/) shows that using a heap to do the selection is faster than Quickselect when the number to be selected is much smaller (less than 1%) of the total number of items. Considering that the log base 2 of 1,000,000 is about 20, it's almost certain that a heap selection algorithm would be faster than Quickselect.